# Is this the correct way to implement multithreading on Server side of concurrent client/server setup?

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I have created this code snippet in both a single threaded version and multithreaded for a client/server setup I have going. I have tested both (recording the avg turn around time) and have gotten EXTREMELY similar results within margin of error when running multiple simple server commands at once. have I implememnted my client handler wrong?

This is my first time trying to implement a multithreaded server and from my understanding it just a matter of putting in a client handler being
`

```
class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
 
    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
```

`
below is the snippet of the whole server code.

`

```
public class Server {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) return;
 
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
 
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
 
            System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);
 
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected");
 
                new ServerThread(socket).start();
            }
 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} 

 class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
 
    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }
 
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
 
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
 
 
            String text;
 
            do {
                text = reader.readLine(); // reads text from client
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(text);
                BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String outputLine;
                while ((outputLine = stdout.readLine()) != null) { // while serverMsg is not empty keep printing
                    writer.println(outputLine);
                }
                stdout.close();

                writer.println("ENDCMD");
                // Text here should just write back directly what the server is reading...?
            }

            while (!text.toLowerCase().equals("exit"));
 
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: It isn't clear what you're measuring.

Comment: Fix your code formatting. Enclose in a pair of triple back-ticks, OR indeed all lines by four spaces.

Comment: Exactly how did you try running multiple simple server commands at once?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tested both (recording the avg turn around time) and have gotten EXTREMELY similar results within margin of error when running multiple simple server commands at once. have I implememnted my client handler wrong?

If you are not making a new connection for each command that you send, then this would be expected. Since each connection runs on one thread, a multi-threaded approach, as you have shown, would have the same speed as if you didn't make a new thread for each connection. The difference is that, without multi-threading, you can only have one connection at a time.